# Shortcuts do not work on the dope sheet. (2.8version)

Tags: shortcut

I am using version 2.8 of Blender.

The following shortcuts do not work on the dope sheet.

Is there a solution?

Ctrl + Shift → : next marker

Ctrl + Shift ← : previous marker

Shift + ↑ 10 : frames forward

Shift + ↓ 10 : frames back

Answer (score 1):

Try Alt + mouse scroller

PS: I'm trying to fix my screencast keys but I was pressing Alt + mouse scroller

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Is there a shortcut to the next marker, not the next keyframe? (version 2.8 of blender)

Answer (score 0):

click on the object you want to set the keyframe and press the button shown in the gif...

[image]